# Service Container issue

Tags: php, laravel

I watched a laravel video course, in it usage of service container was demonstrated in web.php (just as an example) and in web.php it works without any issues:

```
interface KekInterface {};
class Kek implements KekInterface {};
app()->bind('KekInterface', function() { 
    return new Kek;    
});
Route::get('/', function(KekInterface $kekat) {
    dd($kekat);
});
```

I decided to move all my code to a controller(controller class):

```
public function index(KekInterface $api)
{
    dd($api);
}
```

The interface and the class:

```
interface KekInterface {};
class Kek implements KekInterface {};
app()->bind('KekInterface', function() { 
    return new Kek;    
});
```

And then laravel squawked:

> Target [App\Http\Controllers\KekInterface] is not instantiable.

I don't know what causes the problem, but i guess it's just namespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the binding must run inside a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/providers).

Put the `app()->bind(...)` part of code inside the `register` method of `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` class:

```
/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    app()->bind(\Full\Namespace\To\KekInterface::class, function() {
        return new \Full\Namespace\To\Kek();
    })
}
```

Note that `KekInterface` and `Kek` must be inside different files, named by the class name, inside the right folder according to the namespace that you want.

See [`Laravel Service Container docs`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding) to better understanding.

Comment: It worked, although it seems strange to me that it also works in web.php? Btw, talking about service providers, If I pass first argument(class name) to a bind(singleton, etc..) method , but pass another class as the second argument for example: `$this->app->bind('App\Billing\Stripe', function(){return new Kek})` laravel will throw an error, and i think it's kinda weird. Because as i thought before the method registers classes into the container,but came up with that it just edits existing classes that've been auto-resolutioned. Is it actually the way it works?

Comment: It works on web.php because routes are called inside a ServiceProvider (RouteServiceProvider). :-)

Comment: What about binding?

Comment: If it works with interfaces why it doesn't work with classes? but I guess it's a topic for a new question :)

Comment: Not sure about that. :-(